# User unknown in virtual alias table

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I've followed this tutorial to setup mail server on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server
https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

Outgoing emails are working fine but for incoming mail I get this error: 
"User unknown in virtual alias table".

I can't figure it out what I did wrong.

I've searched and tried the solutions mentioned elsewhere but I couldn't get it working.

Following are my settings in /etc/postfix/main.cf 
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost

On more observation is that I see this warning:
warning: do not list domain domain.com in BOTH virtual_alias_domains and virtual_mailbox_domains

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to this problem. I did mistake in copying n pasting *.cf settings from https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql